# HTML5, how to match video current time with caption array to print caption in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I created subtitleArray that get start, duration, and text from XML. Now how can I match with video current play time which included loop and if statement. If it does, it print the caption on website. Here are some code,

```
function init()
            {
                var subtitleArray = new Array();
                var tempArray = new Array();
                var c = document.getElementById('container');

                captionsDoc = loadXMLDoc("captions.xml");
                x=captionsDoc.getElementsByTagName('text');

                for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
                {
                    var tempArray = new Array();
                    tempArray[0] = x[i].getAttribute('start'); // get start time
                    tempArray[1] = x[i].getAttribute('dur'); // get duration time
                    tempArray[2] = x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue; // get text

                    subtitleArray[i] = tempArray; //put all 3 values in array


                }

                video = document.getElementById("caption");

                video.addEventListener('progress', progressHandler);
                     var text = "", cap = "";

                function progressHandler() {

                for( int i = 0; i < subtitleArray.length;i++)
                {
                    var currentTime = video.getCurrentTime();
                    var cueStart = parseFloat(subtitleArray[i][0]);
                    var cueEnd = cueStart + parseFloat(subtitleArray[i][1]);
                    var diff = cueStart - currentTime;
                                cap = subtitleArray[i][2];

                    if (currentTime >= cueStart && currentTime <= cueEnd) {
                       text = cap.text;   
                    }
                }


                c.innterHTML = text;



            }
            window.onload = init;
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <video id="caption" width="320" height="240" controls>
            <source src="caption.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div id="container">
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've looked at it already and dismissed it, but I believe Popcorn.js was designed specifically for this use: http://popcornjs.org/

I believe they have demos of HTML5 video being synched with slide decks, text, etc.

It's open source on Github and has many demos.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I just want simple caption that make it work by matching video current time and then display caption text underneath.

Comment: @StudentIT Understood. If no one else answers, perhaps you can peek in the Popcorn.js code and see how they're monitoring the video time so they can tie events to it.

Comment: How can subtitle XML that had start, dur, and text can work with popcorn-complete.js?